# Extending Dynamic-forms from angular2 cookbook to be able to have arrays

Tags: forms, angular, cookbook

I have tried to extend the Dynamic-Forms app from angular 2 cookbook so I can have an array of multiple fields. I have been able to show the fields, but when I'm filling the form, I'm getting just the last element of the array filled.

Hier is my plunker with that state of the app:

```
//question-array.ts
import { QuestionBase } from './question-base';
export class ArrayQuestion extends QuestionBase<string> {
   controlType = 'array';
   options:{childe:FormElement<string>}[] = [];

   constructor(options:{} = {}){
       super(options);
       this.options = options['options'] || [];
   }
```

}

//question-control.service.ts

...

```
toFormGroup(formelements: QuestionBase<any>[] ) {
let group:any = {};

formelements.forEach(element => {
    console.log("+element",element);
    if(element.controlType === "array"){
        let arr:any[] = [];
        let locobj = {};
        element["options"].forEach((option:any) => {
            option["element"].forEach((e:any) =>{
                locobj[e.key] = new FormControl(e.value || '');
            });
            arr.push(new FormGroup(locobj))
        });
        group[element.key] = new FormArray(arr);
    }else{
        group[element.key] = element.required ? new   FormControl(element.value || '', Validators.required)
                                            : new FormControl(element.value || '');
    }

});
return new FormGroup(group);
```

}

```
//dynamic-form-question.component.html
...
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'array'"  [formArrayName]="question.key">
    <div *ngFor="let item of question.options; let i=index"  [formGroupName]="i" >
        <div *ngFor="let element of item.element">
            <div *ngIf="element.controlType === 'textbox'" >
                <label>{{element.label}}</label>
                <input [formControlName]="element.key" [id]="element.key" [type]="element.type" />
            </div>
            <div  *ngIf="element.controlType === 'dropdown'" >
                <label>{{item.label}}</label>
                <select [id]="element.key" [formControlName]="element.key">
                    <option *ngFor="let opt of element.options" [value]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/DZ05fO

Best regard,
Shefki

Answer (score 1):

I found the bug, the problem was that I was passing the same reference in  the form group her is what i changed:
    //question-control.service.ts
    toFormGroup(formelements: QuestionBase[] ) {
        let group:any = {};

```
   formelements.forEach(element => {
      if(element.controlType === "array"){
          let arr:any[] = [];
          let locobj = {};
          element["options"].forEach((option:any) => {
              option["element"].forEach((e:any) =>{
                 locobj[e.key] = e.value || '';
              });
                   arr.push(new FormGroup(this.getFormControlObject(locobj)));

          });
          group[element.key] = new FormArray(arr);
      }else{
          group[element.key] = element.required ? new   FormControl(element.value || '', Validators.required)
                                        : new    FormControl(element.value || '');
      }

   });
return new FormGroup(group);
}
private getFormControlObject(keys){
    let retobj = {};
    Object.keys(keys).forEach(function(key) {
        retobj[key] = new FormControl(keys[key]);
    });
    return retobj;
}
```

Hier is a working plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/4IMKdLKE51n41jzYY8sU

Comment: In `question-array.ts` - what does this line do `options:{childe:FormElement<string>}[] = [];`

Comment: It's only a type definition you don't have to use that you can use instead `options:any`